# Eclipse - Source not found when trying to open declaration of random()

Tags: java, eclipse

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked, but I didn't find what I wanted in any of the questions. I am a beginner, don't know much about anything.

```
double x = Math.random();
    System.out.println(x);
```

When I press my Ctrl key and press 'Math' keyword it shows source not found, even when I try to open the declaration and implementation of Random, it shows the same error.

**Actual-**
[image: What its showing]

**Expected-**
[image: this is of array list but I want to see similarily for Math.class]

**My compiler settings**
[image: Another pic]

Comment: Are you trying to find the source file to view or the class file to use?

Comment: I am trying to view math class

Comment: It may be getting tripped up since `#random` is a native method, and thus the "implementation" of it isn't actually in java code. Otherwise perhaaps the JDK isn't configured for eclipse, but I'm an intellij man unfortunately

Comment: It happens with every class I try to open, I tried to Open ArrayList, this happened there also.

Comment: You need a JDK to see the source. A JRE is enough to run the code, but only the JDK contains the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `window->preferences->java->installed JRE's`.  Then double click on the one you are using and navigate to the source location and link to the `src.zip` that should come with your JDK.  You should see a window that looks something like the following:  (Note that this is where you would configure the `source` location and the `JavaDoc` for the API).

[image]

Comment: It's only showing jre1.8.0_261 over there which I have already selected.

Comment: Right, but you may not have the source configured.  Double Click on what you see and look at the source location.  And I presume we are not talking about the documentation  (JavaDoc).  You would configure the documentation in the same window.

Comment: @OP Just to be super clear: `JRE`? You mean `JDK`, or are you actually trying to compile on eclipse with a JRE? They're two different tools: JDK for creating code, JRE for executing and running it. Of note to @WJS (since eclipse is outside my boundaries), does eclipse really configure JDK details through a "JRE" window?

Comment: I want to see the documentation of Math.class, wait I will add a pic

Comment: Documentation is completely different than the source.  Here is what I have configured in the same window for documentation.`https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/` You need to go and ensure that the documentation for java 8 is there.  You might just try substituting 8 for 14 and see if it works.

Comment: I double-clicked, it showing a number of files, what to do next?

Comment: Actually, I have a 32 bit OS so can't  download java 14

Comment: Forget about java 14.   That is what I am using but the location of what you want is the same.

Comment: Overhead transmission, I can't get what you are trying to say, you must be correct, but I just want to view what I have shared in the picture. Are there any simple steps to it?

Comment: @Rogue related to your question, all Eclipse needs to use Java is the JRE.  The above just happens to be the location.  Eclipse does not use the JDK.

Comment: Ah right, it ships with its own compiler I think. funky!

Comment: I shared another picture, anything else needs to be done?

Comment: @VyomYadav  The window I have shown in my answer, after double clicking to get to your JRE, did you right click to expand the contents?  You should then see something similar to the image I posted.  If not you need to look at the tools and find add source or add documentation and do what it says.  That is the best I can offer.

Comment: @WJS added another picture, can't find the file named jrt-fs.jar