# Eclipse source attachment configuration path does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed fresh Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0) on Kubuntu OS and jdk 11 via `apt`.

java -version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Problem is when i try to open class/method declaration from jdk
in Eclipse i get message that source is not found.
[image: Source not found]

Tried to locate `src.zip` file [Eclipse - Source not found when trying to open declaration of random()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649046/eclipse-source-not-found-when-trying-to-open-declaration-of-random), but when selecting it, Eclipse interestingly says that the file does not exist. I tought it might be permissions problem as it's path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/src.zip`, but i copied that file to home and nothing changed.

[image]

Any guesses where problem might be?

Comment: It looks like you have installed a JRE instead of a JDK that would work out of the box. Be aware, that OpenJDK also provides not only JDKs, but also JREs. Otherwise, are you sure you a looking at the right JRE/JDK: please show what you have configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ and which one of those do you use in your project.

Comment: The message is missing a `/` in front of `home/...`. A bug?

Comment: @howlger looks like i had JRE installed instead of JDK. Downloaded and installed AdoptOpenJDK 16 (JDK) switched to this in Eclipse and it just works now.

Comment: Great, that it is working now. As an alternative for a JDK installed on your system, [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) provides the AdoptOpenJDK Java 16 JDK as plugin (as part of Eclipse), to run Eclipse and to be used for coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had JRE installed instead of JDK. Downloaded and installed AdoptOpenJDK 16 (JDK) switched to this in Eclipse and it just works now

Answer (score 1):

First download java-17 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/ then open eclipse marketplace and search for java-17 and download the java-17 plugin for eclipse. Then try opening classes in jdk. **It should work**.